# Can I disable TypeScript Inference for imported JS Modules? (Or config it to always infer type: any)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to use a JS module in a TypeScript File. But, because the JS module does not have any type declarations I'm unable to use the JS module because of TypeScript errors

The problem happens because of a default argument in the JS imported function that TypeScript infers as being of one type when it is not.

I know the problem probably only exists because of stupid usage of the default argument, and of a badly written function. But I cannot edit the JS module to correct it.

The real problem is with a React Component that has a prop that defaults to `false` (`const El = ({prop1, prop2 = false})=>{...}`) but could also receive a `number`. Then, when calling the component in the TS file, and when setting that prop to a number (`<El prop1={1} prop2={3}/>`), TypeScript complains with `"Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean | undefined'."`

To simplify, here is an equivalent non-React example:

So, let's imagine one has a TypeScript project with `"allowJS": true` set so a JS module can be imported.

```js
//externalModule.js 
//Can't edit this file
export const addOneOrMore = (a, b = false) => { 
  if(b == false)
    return a + 1
  else
    return a + b
}
```

```js
//typescriptFile.ts
import addOneOrMore from "./externalModule.js"

let one: number = 1
let three: number = 3

console.log(addOneOrMore(one,three)) // TS Error: "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean | undefined'."
```

**I know that what is happening is that the TS Compiler is inferring that, because the argument defaults to `false`, it is of the type boolean.**. And because of that, I can't pass a number to it.

I think that in this case it doesn't make a lot of sense to infer that (at least for imported JS modules without type declarations)

So, my questions are:

- Can I set TSConfig or TypeScript in any way so it overrides the JS inferring always with `: any`?
- Does it make sense to infer `boolean | undefined` is that case? Why `undefined`? Why is more likely that someone would actively pass `undefined` specifically to a default argument than any other type? Why not `boolean | null` or anything else?
- Is there any other way that allows me to use that module in a TS file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> The JS module does not have any type declarations. […] But I cannot edit the JS module to correct it. […] Is there any other way that allows me to use that module in a TS file?

Yes, there is: you can use a [declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)! Just create `externalModule.d.ts` file, put the proper type declarations in it, and you can use the library as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript 3.7, type checking will be disabled on a file if it starts with the following comment:

```js
// @ts-nocheck
```

As already mentioned, in previous versions you can disable checking on a single line by including the following comment on the previous line:

```js
// @ts-ignore
```

In your case, you can try this:

```js
//typescriptFile.ts
import addOneOrMore from "./externalModule.js"

let one: number = 1
let three: number = 3

// @ts-ignore
console.log(addOneOrMore(one,three))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply can't make a change to `externalModule.ts`, then suppressing it with `@ts-ignore` or adding a declaration.d.ts seem like the only way.

If you can still add comments/jsDocs by avoiding code changes, then I'd recommend using `@type` [annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type). For example:

```js
// externalModule.ts

/*
 * @type {(a: boolean, b: boolean | undefined) => number}
 */
export const addOneOrMore = (a, b = false) => { 
  if(b == false)
    return a + 1
  else
    return a + b
}
```

These are ts standards and help it infer types for js code.

Even you can also do that with simple `@param`

```js
// externalModule.ts

/*
 * @param {boolean} a
 * @param {boolean | undefined} b
 */
export const addOneOrMore = (a, b = false) => { 
  if(b == false)
    return a + 1;
  else
    return a + b
}
```